# Creating a pthreads thread pool to handle get requests

Tags: c, networking, pthreads, threadpool

I find it hard to believe there isn't an answer or tutorial for this, but am struggling to find one anywhere!

I have to (and have) build a multithreaded server to handle GET requests in C.
For full marks this needs to use a thread pool. Currently my main thread accepts connections and passes them on to a new thread.

I can find a few implementations of thread pools in c online, but coming from a Java background understanding them is proving difficult. They also all seem to use a task queue.

This seems unnecessary considering you can tell the listen call to queue connections.
I saw somewhere that accept is thread safe (saying that I also hear when POSIX says safe its more of a safeish?)
Is this a sensible approach to take? Or will the overhead be higher with each thread waiting on accept instead of stopping exection until passed a connection?

If that is the case how in C would I go about doing this? I presume i would need to keep a thread safe data structure storing pointers to each thread and a value indicating if they are busy or not?
And have some method to restart the thread and pass it a connection? But I have no idea how to do this and can't find any simple tutorials on the internet.

Any advice or links to tutorials would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Accept()` is [thread-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/threads.html).

Actually what you describe is an elegant way to implement a socket server using a thread pool - call `accept()` in all of them, and the operating system will take care of waking only one thread when a connection arrives. Good job, I have never really thought about this option when I had to implement such things.

As far as I see there's no real overhead in calling `accept()` in multiple threads at the same time - all threads will sleep until a connection can be accepted, so they won't effectively consume any CPU time.

Comment: Do you have a piece of documentation that backs your claim?

Comment: Which claim? That there's no significant overhead? That just seems logical, since the threads are sleeping, waiting in `accept()`.

Comment: No, that accept will block all the threads and return 1 unique file descriptor to only 1 thread.

Comment: Just quickly browsed through `net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c`. But if you take a look at the man page, in it there's no mention of 1. `accept()` not being thread-safe or reentrant (seems obvious, since POSIX requires it to be thread-safe) 2. any return error code indicating a possible race condition.

Comment: Thanks. Other than bad handling of SIGPIPE all is working now :)